# Axios post not works with safari(mac OS) and all ios and mozilla browsers. It works in brave and chrome

Tags: ios, vue.js, post, axios, safari

[Error console screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPd1r.png)
*I saw this error in safari console in chrome there are no these error*

**my method**

```
async postRequest() {
  try {
    const res = await axios.post(baseURL, {

      name: this.formdata.name,
      vd:this.formdata.vd,
      tp:this.formdata.tp,
      email:this.formdata.email,
      tel:this.formdata.tel,
    });

    this.formdata = [...this.formdata, res.data];

  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }

},
```

**that code also not works in ios and safari**

```
postRequest() {
  axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://domain.ru:3000/',
      data: {
        name: this.formdata.name,
        vd:this.formdata.vd,
        tp:this.formdata.tp,
        email:this.formdata.email,
        tel:this.formdata.tel,
      },
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
      }
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log('ÐÑÐ²ÐµÑ ÑÐµÑÐ²ÐµÑÐ° ÑÑÐ¿ÐµÑÐ½Ð¾ Ð¿Ð¾Ð»ÑÑÐµÐ½!');
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });

},
```

*it is not work in safari and ios but works in brave and chrome*

Comment: In what way does it "not work"? What error or behavior are you getting? What debugging steps have you tried?

Comment: connection error

Comment: What *kind* of connection error? What does the error console show? What does the network tab show?

Comment: i add more information

Comment: I don't think that error pictured in the screenshot you added has anything to do with the Axios code. It's a websocket error (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45826271/websocket-is-closed-due-to-suspension-error-on-page-reload).

Comment: i solved that problem

Comment: Hi @АртемМаксимов please update the question with console log either attaching screenshot or log.
If you have already solved this issue please share answer in descriptive manner so that it will be useful for others.

Comment: need debug o/p or error message got on browser console.

Answer (score -2):

for those who faced the same problem
solve:

...
 Submit

Comment: <form onsubmit="return false">

Comment: <button v:on-click="your axios request func">Submit</button>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).